# There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415). Content type 'null' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My Code in RestController class

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/load" , 
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)  //{"application/json", "application/xml"}
public Entity getClaimData(Model model) {
   Entity entity = new Entity("1","2");
   return entity;
}
```

When i am running from browser its showing 
There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415).
Content type 'null' not supported.

I want to return json format as response but not giving output.

Help me out!!!!!

Comment: I added at top of my Controller class with annotation @RestController

Comment: Do the request headers contain the media type for JSON ?

Comment: No am not sending any input request in the form json.

Comment: Please add a request example in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your browser request does not contain `Content-Type`.Please try calling the service using postman by specifying content type `application/json` in header and check.

Other solution would be to remove `consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

maybe：
1. messageConverts do not have json supported
2. Jackson configuration in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a `GET` request and want to add a payload.

It's not a good practice. Usually, `GET` is used only with path varibles or parameters. That's why neither a browser nor Postman put a `Content-Type` header to the request.

I suggest you switch from `GET` to `POST`, you can use just

`@PostMapping("/load")`

annotation.